# MVVM tutorial - 'Wrapping IClientChannel' questions

Tags: mvvm, wcf-client

This is a question on Mark Miller's MVVM tutorial, [here](http://www.developmentalmadness.com/archive/2010/03/08/mvvm-with-prism-101-ndash-part-6b-wrapping-iclientchannel.aspx).

I have 3 questions regarding 'Wrapping IClientChannel'.

**Question 1:**

Mark wrote:

> And here’s how you instantiate ClientChannelWrapper:
>
> IClientChannelWrapper service = new ClientChannelWrapper("BasicHttpBinding_IMessageEndpoint");
>
> Where “BasicHttpBinding_IMessageEndPoint” is the name of your endpoint configuration in your ClientConfig file.

My question is - when I used to do 'Add Service Reference...' - I could create a client object, without having to specify the endpoint string. Using Mark's method - it requires I specify this string, and it seems to be a limitation for me.
Is there anyway to use his 'IClientChannelWrapper' without passing the endpoint string ?
Somehow mimic what the 'Add Service Reference...' does ?

.

**Question 2**

I know that most examples that involve a WPF app contacting a WCF service - use ASYNC operations.
My question is - why is this ?
If I use Mark's method - it means that I need to write 2 interfaces (SYNC and ASYNC), and it seems like overhead.
Why do people not just call the SYNC operation by simply calling it from a separate thread ?

.

**Question 3:**

Does Mark's class also work with 'Duplex' services ?

I have a WCF service that I need to connect to in order to receive notifications from via a callback method.